# Quickest conversion of char to optional boolean in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm doing some data wrangling with R using dplyr.

The data I'm importing is CSV-based and imported with readr.

I have quite a few columns which have "Y" for TRUE, "N" for FALSE, and empty for NA.

Currently I bring them in as factors, and then convert all the affected columns using dplyr::mutate_at with the following function:

```
factor_to_logical_y_na_n <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(
    x == "Y" ~ TRUE,
    is.na(x) ~ NA,
    TRUE ~ FALSE)
}
```

I suspect though there is a more efficient way to do this (which with 300,000 rows and 400 columns would potentially be helpful).

Does anyone have any suggestions of more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Just do `x == "Y"`

Comment: use `stringsAsFactors == FALSE` so you don't have the overhead of converting to and from a factor

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `package`, we can directly use `==` to convert to logical vector and the `NA` values will remain `NA` and all other values that are no "Y" becomes `FALSE`

```
factor_to_logical <- function(x) x == "Y"
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
x1 <- sample(c(LETTERS[20:26], NA), 1e7, replace = TRUE)
system.time(factor_to_logical_y_na_n(x1))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.923   0.158   1.080 
system.time(factor_to_logical(x1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.074   0.003   0.077
```